# What are 'boot' and 'root' options when loading kernel?

Tags: boot, grub2

In the GRUB, to load Ubuntu, we need to load the kernel and initrd as follows

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper
initrd /casper/initrd
```

What does `boot=casper` mean? What is the other option `root`? Is there an equivalent for other distros?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your system and your bootloader on different partitions, set the "boot" argument, otherwise set the "root" argument.